# I cannot view the comments

Tags: comments

I recently developed my wordpress site www.fingeroffury.com for blogging. I have put up a couple of posts which have garnered comments. Unfortunately the comments do not appear on individual posts. I have already checked all the necessary permissions in settings-discussion and also in individual posts but still they do not appear. What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your `single.php` or `single-post.php` in your theme, make sure there's a function `comments_template()`